# Set Timeout for a certain block of code?

Tags: vba, excel, timeout

Is It possible to set a timeout in vba to execute a function or a code block?
The code below sometimes hangs on the open method (It happens when I have networks issues and an Authentication Prompt is displayed) or the code hang on the Run method (When the calculations are too slow).

I would like to kill the excel.exe process if the time to open or to calculate the sheet exceeds 60 seconds.

```
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xlApp.Visible = True
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

  xlApp.Workbooks.Open strpath
  xlApp.Run "CalculateSheet"
  xlApp.Workbooks.Close
  Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: If the size of the XLSX/XLSM workbook is slowing down the opening time, change the format to XLSB. It will significantly reduce the file size and in this way, reduce the time to open the workbook. Once something like a Workbook.Open or Workbook.Calculatie was started, it probably isn't a good idea to abort the procedure even if you could design a multi-thread that could halt the process on a timeout.

Comment: When I open the file the problem is not the size of the file or the time to open. It is that sometimes an Authentication Prompt shows, hanging the code. It rarely happens but I would like that it never happens.   About aborting the procedure I know it isn't a good idea, it also rarely happen, like once in a hundred times, when it happens I have to manually kill the process otherwise the code will be stucked for a long time.

Comment: The problem is that VBA is not multi-threaded, so if the code is doing something (i.e. Opening the Workbook) cannot do other stuffs meanwhile. The idea would be to, before opening the workbook, launching an external script (a VB Script, or a macro into another workbook) that counts 60 seconds and eventually kill the EXCEL.EXE process. But you would realize yourself that the solution is not great, try to rather re-design the process.